# Xamarin IOS needs to redirect to BB Access for OpenID connection

Tags: xamarin.ios, blackberry, mdm, blackberry-dynamics

A client wants to open the BB Access browser when logging in with OpenID (They are using Azure) and i'm having trouble finding docs about this specific issue.

We only want to open BB Access as a browser and let our backend handle the rest of the stuff(Authentication scheme, tokens, etc...). We have no problem on android since we can setup BB Access app as a default browser but it is not possible to do so on IOS.

What is the best way to proceed to resolve this issue? Do I need to implement the whole Dynamics SDK within my app just to open the browser, is there examples of what i'm trying to do anywhere or is there an easier method to do so?

Comment: does BB Access support a custom url scheme?

Answer (score 0):

For BlackBerry Access for iOS, links in third-party, non-BlackBerry Dynamics apps can open in BlackBerry Access if they launch with the following URL scheme: access://open?url= (for example, access://open?url=http://www.blackberry.com).  This does require the UEM Admin to enable the "Allow external apps to open HTTP/HTTPS URLs through BlackBerry Access" app policy for BlackBerry Access.

If your app makes use of a custom URL scheme to get the token back from BlackBerry Access, ensure you also enable that in the BlackBerry Access app policy.  The [BlackBerry Access app configuration settings doc](https://docs.blackberry.com/en/blackberry-dynamics-apps/blackberry-access/3_1/blackberry-access-administration-guide/lnb1484165962504/ndf1494880538789/bcp1488469362943) lists all of these app configuration options.  Specifically, refer to the "Enable 3rd Party Applications" option.

Alternatively, if you do integrate with the BlackBerry Dynamics SDK you could open BlackBerry Access using the [Open HTTP URL Service](https://marketplace.blackberry.com/services/795018).